# VBA (word) Writing a equation in a table

Tags: vba, ms-word, equations

So I am working on a word template which needs to automatically write specific data in specific places of the document. Now I Need to write and mathematical equation in a cell (for example: 〖∆U=α〗_(steel )∙ ∆T ∙ ∆L_vp) I know I need to replace certain characters with a ChrW(###). But I cant seem to figure out how to write the formula in the right format in the cell (specific location in the code below "my equation here". Note this is only one cell as an example but there are more cell that are filled under the *with activedocument.tables*. Can anybody here help me out?

```
'Selecteren Table
With ActiveDocument.Tables(TableNum)

    'Select cell to write data in
        With .cell(r, 1)
        'data to be written in cell    
        With .Range
                .Text = "My Equation here"
            End With
        End With

end with
```

Just to clarify the use of the `with` part of the code

'Select right table
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(TableNum)

```
    'add row when a Tee is already inserted
    If insertrow = True Then
        ActiveDocument.Tables(TableNum).cell(r, 1).Select
        Selection.InsertRows (1)
    End If

    'Select cell and write data
        With .cell(r, 1)
            With .Range
                'lettertype updaten voor betreffende cell
                With .Font
                .Bold = True
                End With
                .Text = TxtTstuk.Value & ":"
            End With
        End With

        'Select cell and write data
        With .cell(r, 2)
            With .Range
                .Text = "Type T-stuk:"
            End With
        End With

        'Select cell and write data
        With .cell(r, 3)
            With .Range
                .Text = TxtTType.Value
            End With
        End With

    'add 1 to counter
    r = r + 1

    'Add row
    If insertrow = True Then
        ActiveDocument.Tables(TableNum).cell(r, 1).Select
        Selection.InsertRows (1)
    Else
        ActiveDocument.Tables(TableNum).Rows.Add
    End If

    'Select cell and write data
        With .cell(r, 2)
            With .Range
                .Text = "Diameter doorgaande leiding:"
            End With
        End With
```

and so on...

Comment: Check this: [Is there any way to write an equation with the equation editor from vba?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4d7471bd-30f0-44e5-8685-79872db03c1f/is-there-any-way-to-write-an-equation-with-the-equation-editor-from-vba?forum=exceldev)

Comment: I have been looking at that code but cant seem to get it working in the with .cell and with .range part of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're only using a single property, what is the purpose of nested `With`?

Modify it to suit your needs.

```
Sub WriteEq()

    Dim objRange As Range
    Dim objEq As OMath

    With ActiveDocument
        Set objRange = .Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range
            objRange.Text = "Celsius = (5/9)(Fahrenheit – 32)"
        Set objRange = .OMaths.Add(objRange)
    End With

    Set objEq = objRange.OMaths(1)
        objEq.ConvertToMathText
        objEq.BuildUp

End Sub
```

Comment: I made an edit to my question to show why i am using the `with`